# Find the constant value of a function which solves a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the value of $k$ for which the constant function $x(t)=k$ is a solution of the differential equation $5 t^2 x' -2 x + 4 = 0$.

Do I derive the $x(t) = k$ to get $x'(t) = 1$ and $x'(t) = 0$ thus making it $t - 2 + 4 = 0$ therefore making it $t + 2 = 0$?

Answer (score 1):

$x(t)=k$ should give you $x'(t)=0$. Also plug in $x(t)=k$, so the differential equation becomes

$$-2k+4=0$$

Then you can find $k$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x(t) = k$ is a solution, then $x'(t) = 0$ (not $1$, as you wrote).  Then you want to solve $-2 x + 4 = 0$ for $x(t) = k$.  Simple.